# connect failed: ECONNREFUSED HttpURLConnection POST internal server Android

Tags: java, android, http-post, httpurlconnection, internal-server-error

My Native Android Application calls the web service hosted in my organization internal server which works in our network.

I am using Async task to do the HTTP POST connection using HttpURLConnection. When I do `DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());`, it is giving `java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.xxx.xxx.xxx (port 90): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)`

```
try {

    for (String currentUrl : urls) {
        // 1. URL
        URL url = new URL(currentUrl);

        // 2. Open connection
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // 3. Specify POST method
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        // 4. Set the headers

            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");


        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        // 5. Add JSON data into POST request body

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        wr.writeBytes(requestObject.toString());

        wr.flush();

        wr.close();

        // 6. Get the response
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);

        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;

        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // 7. Print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    }

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();


} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Where I am going wrong ? Kindly suggest me